# DARK gdk, background covering sprite?

Tags: c++, gdk, game-loop

```
dbLoadImage("media/backdrop.bmp", 2);
dbSprite ( 2, 0, 0, 2 );
dbLoadImage("media/greyback.png", 3);
dbCreateAnimatedSprite(1, "media/bugsheetsheild.png", 3, 1, 1);
```

3 is the background that covers the sprite.
in the game loop this happens

```
dbSprite( 3, greyx, greyy, 3 );
dbSprite ( 1, x, y, 1 );    
dbPlaySprite (1, 1, 3, 100);
```

and basically the first line covers what happens in the next two! I need the sprite with id 1 to appear over the moving background.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

dbSetSpritePriority(1, 10);
solved it. bah